# How to open the powershell app without administrator

Tags: powershell

I have windows 10 machine and with user "aro_user" I logged into the machine and this is default user who is Built-in account for administering the computer/domain.

[image]

Now when I start powershell application (without using run as administrator), the apps always runs with as administrator,

[image]

How to open the powershell app without administrator?

Comment: i might be wrong but this is not normal behavior. usually to always start something as admin one would have to go to compatibility section of properties and check to always run as admin.

Comment: Avoid logging into the machine as this _built-in administrator_ account with SID `S-1-5-21-bla-bla-bla-500` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/security-identifiers-in-windows). Create (and keep using) another account for everyday work…

Comment: Have you changed the UAC setting under "Change User Account Control Settings" to "Never Notify"?  In the powershell shortcut compatibility settings have you selected “Run this program as an admin”?